# Seeking ML Model Recommendations for Enhancing OCR on Corrupted Text Images

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, pytorch, ocr

I am working on a project where I need to perform Optical Character Recognition (OCR) on text-based images. However, these images are corrupted in various ways (e.g., blurred, distorted, low resolution), which significantly diminishes the accuracy of the OCR results.

I have already tried several preprocessing steps, such as dialation/erosion on binary image and also crimmins speckle_= removal , but the outcomes are still not satisfactory. My goal is to enhance the quality or clarity of these corrupted images before applying OCR to improve the accuracy of the text extraction.

I came across a model named OCR-VQGAN, which seems close to what I need, but it's not entirely suited to my specific use case. I am looking for recommendations on machine learning models or approaches that could assist in this scenario. Ideally, I am seeking models that have been successful in:

- Image restoration or enhancement for text-based images.
- Deblurring or denoising text in images.
- Improving the quality of images to enhance OCR accuracy.

Any guidance on existing models, research papers, or GitHub repositories that could aid in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Also, if there are any specific strategies or techniques in image processing or machine learning that you think might be beneficial, I would be very interested to hear about them.

Here is one type of image with what I am working .[image]

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Not really a question about the programming of this, but rather the theory and best practice. Consider asking this somewhere else as well

Answer (score 0):

For enhancing OCR accuracy on corrupted text-images, you can consider using DeblurGAN for image deblurring and SRGAN for super-resolution. Additionally, You should consider applying image processing techniques like histogram equalization and non-local means denoising to further enhance image quality and improve text extraction accuracy.

Comment: the presented input is binarized already. none of your suggestions have a chance of doing anything. your answer is generic, doesn't address the question.